# Laravel 7.x View-related exception after config:cache

Tags: laravel, exception, caching, view, laravel-artisan

I am a junior php developer and very new to laravel. I have the following problem. I cached my config with `php artisan config:cache`, the programm broke with error 500 and in the log i saw the exception shown bellow :

> local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Route [homepage.get] not defined.
>   (View: /var/www/vhosts/sotiris.upgrade/httpdocs/command-center/resources/views/static/includes/header.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError(code: 0): Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Route [homepage.get] not defined.
>    (View: /var/www/vhosts/sotiris.upgrade/httpdocs/command-center/resources/views/static/includes/header.blade.php) at /var/www/vhosts/sotiris.upgrade/httpdocs/command-center/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:0).

I cleared everything in cache and it worked. Can anyone please help me ? Any steps?? Files to look for ? Anything

Comment: show your routes code

Comment: You have used the route named 'homepage.get' in header.blade.php but it is not defined in web.php or api.php. Share your web.php and api.php code

Comment: show your route file web.php